# Casablanca with boost 1.56 fails due to -Werror

Tags: c++, boost, casablanca

I'm trying to build [Casablanca](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20Linux&referringTitle=Documentation) with boost 1.56, but my build keeps failing due to boost warnings turned error by Casablanca's `-Werror` flag

For example:

```
CXX=g++ BOOST_ROOT=${boost} cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Yields errors like (far too many to show)

```
/home/matt/workspace/opal2/o2linux64/Libs/boost/1.56/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222:36: error: ‘boost::system::errno_ecat’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
 static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
                                ^
/home/matt/workspace/opal2/o2linux64/Libs/boost/1.56/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223:36: error: ‘boost::system::native_ecat’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
 static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
                                ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/client/http_client_msg.cpp.o] Error 1
```

I can't seem to find any remedy on google, though I have found posts where people have built with 1.56 and don't mention disabling `Werror` in  `src/CMakeList.txt` (which incendentally seems to allow the code to build)

Comment: Ooops. I didn't actually read that too well. If it's those warnings, don't build boost with -Werror. It won't work.

Comment: The `-Werror` is in the Casablanca `CMakeLists.txt` file..  It must be in there for a reason - or rather, it would be odd for everyone to have to remove it manually. :S

Answer (score 2):

To prevent editing Casablanca's CMakeLists.txt, you can add -DWERROR=OFF parameter when running cmake command, e.g:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWERROR=OFF <path to src>
```

Please note, that cmake can cache options values, so it's better to re-run cmake in a clean build directory

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of this option.  I'll see if I can try rebuilding it sometime today, and hopefully mark this question as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This option was added on 2016-02-02 according to the git history, so this answer is useless if you use earlier version of the repository.
You can see this option at the top of Release/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Ahh, I see it.  It's not in the master branch (as of today), but in the `prerelease-3.0.0` branch.  Good to know, I'll modify my build script to set it once I'm using version 3, but until then I'm stuck with running `sed -i 's/-Werror//' Release/src/CMakeLists.txt`  Thanks

Comment: Hi Matt,

yes, unfortunately this fix isn't in master. Sorry for this.

However if your aim is to prevent editing casablanca's cmake files, you still have an option:

run cmake with this parameter:
`-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-isystem <boost include dir>"`

in my case it looks like this:
`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-isystem /home/user/proj/boost/include`

Boost headers will be treated as system headers (they are system headers in fact) and thus boost warnings will be suppressed.
It's rather a hack but it works for me:)
If it's ok for you, I can update the answer

Comment: note: it works because -isystem include stays later then -I include, and thus overwrite it

Comment: another note: it was tested with gcc compiler

Comment: I always wondered what `-isystem` actually did.  I mightn't apply it to my Casablanca build, but I think this could be a good addition to my build scripts for our main product.  Right now I've spent a lot of time putting platform agnostic warning suppression pragmas around my boost includes, this could solve that issue in a much cleaner way.